# DocuSign field mandatory/not mandatory per REST request

Tags: docusignapi

I have a question: is it possible to choose a field to be mandatory or not mandatory per DocuSign REST request when we are forming an envelope?

In some cases I need field to be mandatory, in other - not (or even not usable)

Comment: Please don't forget to "upvote" and "accept" Karan Kaushik's reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, document tabs have parameters `required` which can be set to true or false.

They also have the parameter `readOnly` which can also be set to true or false

The [API reference](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocumenttabs/create/) has all the parameters in it

Comment: Remember to mark the question as answered if I've answered your query :)